# Fatal Python error в PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Создаю проект в PyCharm с виртуальным окружением poetry, подключаю git. Все работает до перезахода в PyCharm, потом при любой попытке запустить файл через PyCharm получаю ошибку

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\hashes-and-encodings-Dxk8htuy-py3.11\Scripts\python.exe D:\Pycharm-project\hashes-and-encodings\main.py 
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = 'D:\Pycharm-project\hashes-and-encodings;D:/Apps/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/223.8836.43/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend;D:/Apps/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/223.8836.43/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_display'
  program name = 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib'
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311'
  sys.platlibdir = 'DLLs'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\pypoetry\\Cache\\virtualenvs\\hashes-and-encodings-Dxk8htuy-py3.11\\Scripts\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311'
  sys.path = [
    'D:\\Pycharm-project\\hashes-and-encodings',
    'D:\\Apps\\JetBrains\\Toolbox\\apps\\PyCharm-P\\ch-0\\223.8836.43\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend',
    'D:\\Apps\\JetBrains\\Toolbox\\apps\\PyCharm-P\\ch-0\\223.8836.43\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display',
    'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python311.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib',
    'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding

Current thread 0x000031f0 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Пробовал пересоздавать виртуальное окружение, эффект тот же.
При запуске файла через консоль: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\hashes-and-encodings-Dxk8htuy-py3.11\Scripts\python.exe D:\Pycharm-project\hashes-and-encodings\main.py` - ошибок нет

os: Windows 11
python: 3.11.2

UPD 1:
Переустановка Python и PyCharm не решило проблему

UPD 2:
Может ли все падать с ошибкой из-за того что в `PYTHONPATH` после `D:\Pycharm-project\hashes-and-encodings` идут ссылки с другим слешом, и можно ли эти ссылки оттуда убрать?

Comment: Вам может помочь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65184937/fatal-python-error-init-fs-encoding-failed-to-get-the-python-codec-of-the-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой проект содержит следующую структуру:
[image: Структура проекта]

Проблема заключалась в наличии пакета `encodings`. Наличие этого пакета ломает Python по неизвестным мне причинам, если кто-то знает дайте ссылку, где можно прочитать про этот пакет.

Проблема решается удалением `__init__.py` из `encodings`, либо переименованием пакета.

Comment: Потому что у питона есть стандартный пакет с таким именем. А при импорте ваш локальный пакет грузится первым, в том числе когда `encodings` пытаются импортировать какие-то библиотеки, которые вы импортируете. Поэтому нельзя называть свои файлы и пакеты так же, как называются стандартные пакеты питона. Такие ошибки не всегда легко понять.